# SQL server Update Dynamic Column for Some row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following Data

```
----------------------------------------------
Program | GN | GNF | SC |SCF
----------------------------------------------
P01     | 10 | 2   | 5  | 2
P02     | 10 | 2   | 5  | 2
```

I want:
User execute stored procedure setQuota with parameters @PROGRAM say P02, and some @category say GNF .

Result should be:
Decrease value of Program for that category by one.
that is, for P02 GNF would be 1

I have following Code

```
 DECLARE @SEATCAT NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'GEN'
 DECLARE @PROG NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'U03'
 declare @sql1 nvarchar(max)

 begin
 declare @sql nvarchar(max)
 set @sql = 'Update SHEAT SET [' + @SEATCAT + '] = [' + @SEATCAT + ']-1 Where PROGRAM='' + P01 +''';     
 exec sp_executesql @sql
 end

 Select GEN FROM SHEAT Where PROGRAM=@PROG;`
```

I am getting errors:

Comment: Please add errors, and expected output.

Comment: you are missing an apostrophe. should be: `Where PROGRAM=''' + P01 +'''`

Comment: Thanks to all. I Update result as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a quote and also are using `P01` like a variable but it isn't defined. Did you mean to write `@PROG` so it would be like

```
Where PROGRAM=''' + @PROG + ''';
```

As a further note: If either of these variables are coming from user input (eg someone types them in) then you should really look into [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks as you may be allowing arbitrary code to be run through this procedure.